# My javascript function works only after I hard refresh the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I know that there are multiple questions about this same problem, but I couldn't find an answer in any of them. I'm using javascript to activate hover on other elements. The javascript code works fine but it only works after I hard refresh the page, CTRL + R. If I go to the page normally it won't work.

**JS:**

```js
      $(function() {
      $('#faqBg').hover(function() {
      $('#spanContainer').css('background', 'rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.6');
      }, function() {
        // on mouseout, reset the background colour
      $('#spanContainer').css('background', '');
      });
    });
```

```css
.image-wrapper {
 position: relative;
}
 
 #faqBg { 
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg,rgba(0,0,0,.5),rgba(0,0,0,.5)),url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/1239162/pexels-photo-1239162.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500);
    padding: 60px 0px;
    display: block;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    
 #spanContainer {
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="image-wrapper">

<div id="faqBg">

<div id="spanContainer">

Hover trigger

</div>

</div>

</div>
```

This is the code Im using, here when I do it everything seems allright, but on the website it doesnt. I tried adding `$(document).ready` and `$(document).load` but it didnt worked.

Comment: I tested with Chrome [Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)] and worked just fine: https://trustmypetsitter.herokuapp.com/faq

Comment: why are you using JS to trigger hover at all? Why not simply use CSS? Have you tried with CSS ?

Comment: When you land on the page it works, but can you navigate to some other page and then return to the faq, it wont work.

Comment: Why are you doing stuff that CSS can handle perfectly on its own, using JavaScript in the first place? `#faqBg:hover #spanContainer { /*format me like one of your french girls*/ }`

Comment: @Davashish I haven't, I didn't had luck with css, couldn't make it working so I used jQuery.

Comment: @FreelancerHelp I have posted a simple CSS answer below. Try using it and see if it works for you. If it does, mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CSS instead:

```
 #faqBg:hover #spanContainer { 
       background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
 }
```

Comment: Hey @Devashish. Yes using CSS helped, it doesn't require hard refresh now. Thanks!!!

Comment: It's strange that this got marked as the answer. The OP asked a question about a javascript function, not about how to change a background color using css.

Answer (score 6):

This is happening because of cache.

**Add version to you javascript file on loading:**

`<script src="file.js?v=1"></script>` Increment the `v` parameter on each change you want to see.
If your page is generated dynamically you can set to `v` a timestamp value, depends on the backend language you are using.

**Another solution is to use these meta tags:**

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrei, I tried it but no luck. This app is running on React so thats maybe why this answer isnt working.

Comment: so, your React app is not updating ?

Comment: the problem actually is related to cache. That's why is working when you hard reload the page. But you can put the meta tags within index.html from React. Don't you  ?

Comment: Well yes and this is the only page thats having this issue, I used this same javascript to trigger hover on homepage and there it all works fine.

Comment: I added the meta tags you provided aswell as the ?v=1 but its the same.

Answer (score 3):

The javascript function in your code includes style change, which will be reflected after a hard refresh.

Can you please confirm whether any other JS function(a function without style change) acts the same way you mentioned.